Nginx Alias To Serve Static Files With A Variable In The Path
I have an nginx service that makes heavy use of maps to produce different redirects based on each user. I have used these variable fine in proxy_pass calls.
I now want to serve static files from a directory based on who is logged in.
I am trying to use something like this:
location ~ /images/(.*\.(jpg|jpeg))$ {
        alias /www/foo/$map_user/$1;
}

It fails to work.
If I use a static version for my test user:
location ~ /images/(.*\.(jpg|jpeg))$ {
        alias /www/foo/test/$1;
}

it works.
Anyone know how to get this to work as I want it to so I can use the same path on the site but have it look in the directory for the user logged in? I basically don't want users being able to try guessing other users directories to see their images.

Check the error log. You may see the path that Nginx is trying. Are you sure that $map_user is defined for image requests?

The error log simply states that the call to /images/*.jpg fails, it doesn't say what path was tried. I know $map_user is defined for other location calls (using proxy_pass). Do I need to do something special to make it defined for an alias?

There are two logs, the access log and the error log. Are you checking the correct log?

I checked both. They both simply list the call to /images/*.jpg. They don't say where that aliased to.

I think the reason your solution isn't working is somewhat similar to the one answered here - the $1 variable gets overwritten while you evaluating $map_user variable. Try to use named captures, e.g.:
location ~ /images/(?<image>.*\.jpe?g)$ {
        alias /www/foo/$map_user/$image;
}

